# How to add multiple css rules to minimize browser reflows?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, browser, reflow

Let's say I need to apply bunch of css rules (around 50) like as following code:

```
 var s = document.createElement('style');
     s.type = 'text/css';
     s = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(s);

 var cssRules = [
      ".someClass1 {text-align: center; color: red;}",
      ".someClass2 {border: 1px solid black;}",
      ".someClass3 {color: green;}",
      ".someClass4 {text-decoration: underline; color: red;}",
      ...
 ];

 if (s.sheet && s.sheet.insertRule) {
     for (var i = 0, len = cssRules.length; i<len; i++) {
         s.sheet.insertRule(cssRules[i], s.sheet.cssRules.length);
     }         
 }
```

So every call of `s.sheet.insertRule` triggers browser reflow. How could I minimize browser reflows to just once?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not have them in a CSS file and load the file when needed?

Comment: Modern browsers are generally smart enough to figure out reflows when adding multiple styles in the same script, of course that is for the normal use of javascripts `element.style`, when using the rather homely insertion of rules to a sheet, I'm not sure what it does ?

Comment: @Mooseman Because I have cssRules after some user actions after the page is loaded.

Comment: @adeneo Unfortunately I can't use `element.style` for my reason. So I'm looking for an approach to optimize my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `join` all your rules into a single string:

```
// Join rules and use a space as delimiter
var cssRulesAppended = cssRules.join(' ')
```

You can also directly write your CSS into your head by adding a `style` tag, skipping the `insertRule` method altogether:

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    styleTag = document.createElement('style')

styleTag.type = 'text/css'

if (styleTag.styleSheet) {
    styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = cssRulesAppended
} else {
    styleTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cssRulesAppended))
}

head.appendChild(styleTag)
```

**Edit:**
If you already know the rules you're going to add, I would strongly advise against inserting them the way you're doing now. Either put them into a stylesheet to use at page load start, or, if you're aware of the elements needing the specific styles, using the style properties of JavaScript. Here's a JSPerf: [link](http://jsperf.com/css-insertrule-vs-style-properties/5).

Comment: @answered Thanks for the reply. I'm trying yours approach in my code.

Comment: @Erik I checked the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule) for `insertRule`, and it doesn't allow batch operations (as in multiple rules in one statement). So if you want to insert multiple rules at once, you'll have to use the <style> tag approach.